# Using pseudo-TTY with Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

Is it possible to start docker containers in Azure with the docker --tty argument through the Azure Command-line Interface? I see nothing in the documentation and I'd like to be able to attach to a tmux session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add the parameter `--tty` is to create a terminate and interact with the container instance. But it's not a parameter supported by Azure Container Instance. You can see all the supported parameters in CLI commands [`az container`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest). To create a terminate and interact with the container instance, you could use the CLI command [`az container exec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-exec) to achieve it, just like:

```
az container exec -g MyResourceGroup --name mynginx --container-name nginx --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```